# Deleting all network shares from a Windows system in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm attempting to remove all the shares hosted on a Windows 7 machine with a batch script.

**Code**

```
@echo off

REG QUERY HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares > %APPDATA%\shares.txt

findstr /I /V HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE %APPDATA%\shares.txt | findstr /I /V HKLM >> %APPDATA%\shares2.txt

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=1" %%S in (%APPDATA%\shares2.txt) do (
    set tempy=%%S
    net share "!tempy!" /delete
)
ENDLOCAL
```

**shares.txt** (after running)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares
Test    REG_MULTI_SZ    CSCFlags=0\0MaxUses=4294967295\0Path=C:\Test\0Permissions=0\0Remark=\0ShareName=Docs\0Type=0
Sp aces    REG_MULTI_SZ    CSCFlags=0\0MaxUses=4294967295\0Path=C:\Test\0Permissions=0\0Remark=\0ShareName=Sp aces\0Type=0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares\Security
```

**shares2.txt** (after running)

```
Test    REG_MULTI_SZ    CSCFlags=0\0MaxUses=4294967295\0Path=C:\Test\0Permissions=0\0Remark=\0ShareName=Docs\0Type=0
Sp aces    REG_MULTI_SZ    CSCFlags=0\0MaxUses=4294967295\0Path=C:\Test\0Permissions=0\0Remark=\0ShareName=Sp aces\0Type=0
```

I'm testing it with two shares, "Test" and "Sp aces"

I was able to delete the `test` share, but I was unable to delete the `sp aces` share because `"tokens=1"` only grabs the first word.  How can I adjust this so that it will work for single words and words with spaces?

Comment: 1. `set temp = %%S` --> `set temp=%%S` or `set "temp=%%S"`; 2. do not use variable name `temp` as this is already used by the system...

Comment: Change `tokens=1` to either `tokens=*` (removes leading white-spaces) or `delims=` (does not remove anything)...

Comment: Using tokens = * passes the entire line from the second text file though, not just the name. And the length of the share name is arbitrary, so I can't set token accordingly.

Comment: True. Not that easy. Could the last part in `shares2.txt` also contain spaces? And could the name contain four adjacent spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing...:

- `shares2.txt` uses four adjacent spaces as column separator;
- the share names do not contain four adjacent spaces;
- the share names do not contain the `|` character;
- the share names do not contain the `!` character;
- the share names do not begin with the `;` character;

...the following code might work for you:

```dos
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%S in ("%APPDATA%\shares2.txt") do (
    set "tempy=%%S"
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=|" %%N in ("!tempy:    =|!") do (
        net share "%%N" /delete
    )
)
endlocal
```

---

Here is an improved variant which allows share names to contain `!` and to begin with `;`:

```dos
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%S in ("%APPDATA%\shares2.txt") do (
    set "tempy=%%S"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=|" %%N in (^""!tempy:    =|!"^") do (
        endlocal
        net share "%%~N" /delete
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: It is unlikely that the shares I'm working with would contain such characters.  Thanks for the easy to read code and answer!

Answer (score 0):

One batch file, no temp files, completely untested and may not even work with some data types:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=2* Delims==;" %%A In ('WMIC Class StdRegProv Call EnumValues^
 "&H80000002"^, "System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares"
 ^|Find "sNames"') Do Set "_=%%A"
For %%A In (%_:~2,-1%) Do Net Share %%A /Delete
```

Comment: Hi Compo. I created two shares on my computer and it does not enumerate either one of them.